# R merging two timestamp indexes and reindexing with missing keys

Tags: r

Suppose I have two data frames like this: (ALL the time are stored as POSIXct)

```
A
time                            price 
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993772 CDT  249.13  
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993780 CDT  249.14  
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993791 CDT  249.15  

B
time                            price 
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993772 CDT  249.20  
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993783 CDT  249.30  
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993792 CDT  249.40
```

What I want to do is to 'reindex' A use the union of the index from A and B
, and then forward fill the data, and getting:

```
C
time                            price 
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993772 CDT  249.13  
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993780 CDT  249.14  
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993783 CDT  249.14  
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993791 CDT  249.15 
2017-09-25 03:30:02.993792 CDT  249.15
```

Comment: You already had some of it.  `df[c(1,2,4,3,2),, drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Sorry, I may misrepresent my problem, actually the index is not the numeric index, it's something in another columns.

Comment: Oh, well then provide a reproducible example with data that is representative of the actual data.

Comment: Thanks. I already updated my questions using the real data. Anyone could help solve it ?

Comment: *index*? *reindex*? *forward fill*? Sounds like python pandas terminology.

Comment: Yes. Since I used to work with Python and just switched to R for a new job.